# Get PR number from github templates

Tags: github

I create a new environtment for my backend for each commit, this environment have the PR number on the URL.

So I was hopping to create a template so that everytime someone creates a PR the text contains the URL for that enviroment, something like:

Im expecting to have a template `pull_request_template.md` like:

```
# How to test
Url: http://myurl-<PR-number>.myhost.com
```

And so everytime the PR

```
# How to test
Url: http://myurl-123.myhost.com
```

Where `123` is the PR number

Comment: Pretty nice idea, would be helpful for my project as well. It seems there are some discussion going on: https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/333, maybe it would be helpful to submit a feature request to github or ask them for help using their form at https://support.github.com/contact/feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As illustrated [in here](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Multiple-Pull-Request-Template/m-p/6582/highlight/true#M2181) and in [this discussion](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Multiple-Pull-Request-Templates/m-p/20942/highlight/true#M6165), you can have and use multiple template files (adding `?template=MY_PR_TEMPLATE.md`), but not one file with variable content.

In your case, that wouldn't work.

What might work is a [Pull Request Action](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#pull-requests), which would add a [label and/or message](https://github.com/loomble/pull-request-stuck-notifier-action), with said message being the URL computed automatically from the PR number.
That [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) would help updating any PR with an additional information: the URL you want.

Comment: Thanks! but that still dont meet my expectations an the answer

Comment: @DanielGomezRico It does if it modified the PR to add the requested URL.

Comment: I dont see any way to have a Github Action that edit the PR description text, can you show me one way to do this?

Comment: @DanielGomezRico This one creates a PR through an API calls (https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request): you could consider patching an existing PR instead: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I havent implemented it but I will try it out in the future